# Selecting a valid format file

Tags: shapefile, error, import, carto

There has been an error when uploading a shapefile

I want to start with some imported data. Upload a file.

```
Please, select a valid format file

# when upload a zip file:
```

> Oops! There has been an error
>   Unknown
>   Code 99999
>       Begin:
>       TRANSITION: preprocessing => uploading, 2014-01-07 02:59:15 -0800
>       getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
>       Table error, #

Comment: have you uploaded a shapefile or a zip file?

Comment: when uploaded a zip file that error is Oops! There has been an error

Unknown Code 99999

Begin:
TRANSITION: preprocessing => uploading, 2014-01-07 02:59:15 -0800
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Table error, #

Comment: when uploaded a .shp file it shows......Please, select a valid format file

Comment: did you make sure that .SHP, .DBF, .SHX and .PRJ are in your zip file ?

Comment: i followed this link  http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/conditional_styling.html

Answer (score 1):

Export the whole shapefile in the GIS of your choice as a geoJSON and import it to cartoDB. I personally think GeoJSON is easier to edit and share than shp-files.

Comment: how to know which version of cartodb we r using????